# Android - Retrofit being received as null when the model contains a byte[]

Tags: java, android, asp.net-web-api, retrofit

I'm using Retrofit to post some data back to my WebAPI REST service. However, if my model contains a `byte[]`, the value received by WebAPI is null. If I remove the property `Signature` then the model is received as expected with the rest of the values.

Also, leaving the `Signature` property null will also work. It's only when the signature has content that the WebAPI receives a null value.

The byte array contains the PNG signature image captured on the device.

Here's my model, containing the `byte[]` property:

```
public class RefundDto {
    public String Id;
    public String Amount;
    public int AssetId;
    public String Comments;
    public String DateCreated;
    public String DateModified;
    public int FaultId;
    public int RefundActionId;
    public int SiteId;
    public int UserId;

    public byte[] Signature; // The culprit
}
```

I send my model using the following code:

```
RefundDto dto = getDto();
service.postRefund(dto, new Callback<RefundDto>() {
    @Override
    public void success(RefundDto dto, Response response) {
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        db.deleteRefund(dto.Id);
        db.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
    }
});
```

My DataService method for Retrofit looks like this:

```
@POST("/refunds")
void postRefund(@Body RefundDto model, Callback<RefundDto> callback);
```

Which I am sending to the following rest method:

```
public class RefundsController : ApiController
{
    public RefundDto Post([FromBody]RefundDto value)
    {
        // value is null!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to sort this. I changed the `byte[]` to a `String` and sent the Signature as a Base64 encoded string:

```
dto.Signature = new String(Base64.encode(getSignature(), 0));
```

I left my server side model using a `byte[]` and WebAPI took care of the conversion.

Comment: That's the only way I found out so far.